# Select the first 25 items of a certain column in SAP GUI whose name I know

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to select the first 25 items of a certain column in SAP GUI whose name I know. I recorded a script and it came like that shown below.

As you can see the name of the columns are ST_RESERVA, FEVOR, AUFNR, MATNR, ZAGRLOGISTICO and MATNR.

The code works fine but I think I could simplify this using FOR with the rows going to 1 until 25 and the column fixed. Any ideas?

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject app, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").setCurrentCell 10,"ST_RESERVA"
set coll1 = app.createGuiCollection
coll1.add "10,ST_RESERVA"
coll1.add "10,FEVOR"
coll1.add "10,AUFNR"
coll1.add "10,MATNR"
coll1.add "10,ZAGRLOGISTICO"
coll1.add "10,MAKTX"
coll1.add "11,ST_RESERVA"
coll1.add "11,FEVOR"
coll1.add "11,AUFNR"
coll1.add "11,MATNR"
coll1.add "11,ZAGRLOGISTICO"
coll1.add "11,MAKTX"
coll1.add "12,ST_RESERVA"
coll1.add "12,FEVOR"
coll1.add "12,AUFNR"
coll1.add "12,MATNR"
coll1.add "12,ZAGRLOGISTICO"
coll1.add "12,MAKTX"
coll1.add "13,ST_RESERVA"
coll1.add "13,FEVOR"
coll1.add "13,AUFNR"
coll1.add "13,MATNR"
' and the list goes on until the first 25 items are selected from the tables above.
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedCells = coll1
set coll1 = nothing
```

Comment: It's the property `ColumnOrder`, it is a collection containing all the column names. More information is given in the `GuiGridView` documentation, which is publicly available in the Web.

Comment: I couldn't get ColumnOrder from this https://help.sap.com/docs/IRPA/8ecea00c1f854fd0a433c4aef5da1ea2/b21b0e511b11448eb44884aa1c3a8f9e.html could you provide me the correct so I can study more?

Comment: Weird that you don't find it with your favorite search engine, with both words `ColumnOrder` and `GuiGridView`. Here is a more direct search query (but may not work anymore in the future): https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=ColumnOrder%20GuiGridView&product=sap_gui_for_windows

Comment: Hi, Sandra! I saw that you modified my question but the thing is I don't wanna get the names of the columns, sorry if I wasn't clear. I would like the select the first 25 items of those columns whose names are "ST_RESERVA", "FEVOR", "AUFNR", "MATNR" and "ZAGRLOGISTICO". As you saw my code it looks too long so I was wondering if I could use For to simplifiy this (I would use a FOR for each different column).

Comment: Then, could you edit your question to fix the title and clarify your requirement please? In fact, you could find existing answers by just searching the `vba` tag, it's not specific to SAP GUI. It's 2 nested loops, the first one from 10 to 12, and the second one based on an array or collection of String. e.g. `Dim columns() As String : columns = split("ST_RESERVA;FEVOR",";") : for i = 10 to 12 : for j = lbound(columns) to ubound(columns) : coll1.add i & "," & columns[j] : next : next`.

Comment: thanks, Sandra. I just edited the question. Also, the last answer of yours helped me a lot.